# Does minimizing the mean of Varience of an unbiased estimator by selecting the values of ${\bf{r}}$, imply minimizing the mean of CRLB?

Tags: variance, unbiased-estimator

I can minimize the mean  of variance of an unbiased estimator of a paramater $\theta$ by selecting the values of a set of parameters, ${\bf{r}}$. So i can minimeze ${\rm{E[Va}}{{\rm{r}}_{\hat \theta }}({\bf{r}},\theta)]$, with mean on $\theta$. Does minimizing the statistical mean of variance ($\theta$ is uniformly distributed) imply minimizing the mean of CRLB, i.e. ${\rm{E[CRB}}({\bf{r}},\theta )] $ so that the two procedures of minimizing of two quantities produce the same result for ${{\bf{r}}_{Optimum}}$?
Can i proof this by using the CRLB inequality and how?

Comment: I think some of your hats are in the wrong places. Are you saying $\hat{\theta}$ is uniformly distributed (on some support)?

Comment: $\hat \theta$ (with hat) is the estimator of $\theta$, which is considered a random variable (as in a Bayesian Approch) and distributed uniformly

Comment: In your question can you clarify how CRLB depends on $r$? As far as I know CRLB tells you that $\Var[\hat{\theta}_r(X)] \geq \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$ for each fixed $\theta$. The bound doesn't seem to involve $r$.

Comment: in some cases it is possible to minimize the CRLB by suitably varying the values of a set of parameters. In my case the CRLB (or the Fisher Information) depends on ${\bf{r}} = ({x_1},{y_1},{x_2},{y_2},...,{x_n},{y_n})$ as well as depending on $\theta$. Therefore, i can reduce the CRLB by selecting appropriate values of ${\bf{r}}$.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a case? I don't yet understand what $r$ is. Is it the observed data?

Comment: however I have a particular case. I have an expression for the variance of an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ which depends on both $\theta$ and ${\bf{r}} = ({x_1},{y_1},{x_2},{y_2},...,{x_n},{y_n})$. I want to show that minimizing the mean value of the CRLB is equivalent to minimizing the mean value of the Variance (i.e. I can say that the two minimization problems have the same solution ${{\bf{r}}_{Optimum}}$. For example if I knew that the estimator is an efficient estimator, there would be the sign of equality in Cramer-Rao inequality and it would be easy to prove it.

Comment: ${\bf{r}} = ({x_1},{y_1},{x_2},{y_2},...,{x_n},{y_n})$ in my particular case, are the locations of sensors through which to estimate the angle $\theta$